# Embedded JS data not inputting on Qualtrics Data & Analysis

Tags: javascript, url, embed, qualtrics, referrer

I've need my survey to collected information on the page URL from which the survey was accessed from.

On the survey workflow, the referrer embedded should do this but it doesn't give me the full URL.

I've created a new field called RefURL as shown:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvIr.png)

I've also edited the Java script for the first question on my survey, here's the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcqn4.png)

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use setJSEmbeddedData("RefURL",a) then you have to define the embedded data field in the survey flow as __js_RefURL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that fixed it as I can see it is recording data now. 

I have another problem now which is it is not recording the full URL.

Let's say my the referrer URL is: website.com/folder/link

It is only recording it as: website.com

Here's my code:

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{


});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
 
  var a = window.frames.top.document.referrer;

  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setJSEmbeddedData("RefURL", a );
 

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{

});

Comment: You can pipe the survey url as "${e://Field/Q_URL}"